# Select with group by takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have a problem selecting from a table. I'm running the following query:

```
DECLARE @FactId nvarchar (MAX)

set @FactId = '2379233,2379237,2379244,2379246,2379249,2379250,2379254,2379255,2379257,2379260,2379262,2379264,2379266,2379268,2379270,2379276,2379279,2379284,2379285,2379293,2379294,2379298,2379300,2379305,2379308,2379310,2379313';

BEGIN

SELECT  
    (apd.USS) as USS, (apd.Area) as Area, P.[Description] 
FROM
    [gisoo].AdministrationPileDetail apd
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Locality L on L.LocalityId = apd.LocalityId
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Province P on P.CountryId = L.CountryId AND P.Provinceid = L.ProvinceId
WHERE 
    apd.FactId IN (SELECT * FROM  [gisoo].[ItemListToTable](@FactId))
    AND L.ProvinceId IS NOT NULL
    AND L.DepartmentId IS NOT NULL
END
GO
```

This select divides the `nvarchar` (`@FactId`) into a table with all separated id:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  [gisoo].[ItemListToTable](@FactId)
```

The query has 12000 rows and it takes two seconds, but when I run the group by it takes 40 seconds.

```
DECLARE @FactId nvarchar (MAX)

set @FactId = '2379233,2379237,2379244,2379246,2379249,2379250,2379254,2379255,2379257,2379260,2379262,2379264,2379266,2379268,2379270,2379276,2379279,2379284,2379285,2379293,2379294,2379298,2379300,2379305,2379308,2379310,2379313';

BEGIN

SELECT  
    SUM(apd.USS) AS USS, 
    SUM(apd.Area) AS Area, 
    P.[Description] 
FROM 
    [gisoo].AdministrationPileDetail apd
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Locality L ON L.LocalityId = apd.LocalityId
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Province P ON P.CountryId = L.CountryId AND P.Provinceid = L.ProvinceId
WHERE 
    apd.FactId IN (SELECT * FROM  [gisoo].[ItemListToTable](@FactId))
    AND L.ProvinceId IS NOT NULL 
    AND L.DepartmentId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    P.[Description]
END
GO
```

Both tables don't have indexes.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and the query It was also tested in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What type is the Description Column? Have you checeked the query plan? Have you tried to index the Description Column?

Comment: Description char(30) null.

I check the plan and says I can optimize only 30% using index . Remains a long time to my query.

the table province where extract data description only has 71 rows.

Comment: Finally , complete the group by the application , the response was only 3 seconds. I not found my problem within the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Try this
And replace SELECT * FROM with a specific column name

```
set @FactId = '2379233,2379237,2379244,2379246,2379249,2379250,2379254,2379255,2379257,2379260,2379262,2379264,2379266,2379268,2379270,2379276,2379279,2379284,2379285,2379293,2379294,2379298,2379300,2379305,2379308,2379310,2379313';

BEGIN

SELECT SUM(apd.USS) AS USS, 
       SUM(apd.Area) AS Area, 
       P.[Description] 
  FROM [gisoo].AdministrationPileDetail apd
  JOIN [gisoo].Locality L 
        ON L.LocalityId = apd.LocalityId
       AND L.DepartmentId IS NOT NULL
       AND apd.FactId IN (SELECT * FROM  [gisoo].[ItemListToTable] (@FactId))          
  JOIN [gisoo].Province P 
        ON P.CountryId  = L.CountryId 
       AND P.Provinceid = L.ProvinceId          
 GROUP BY P.[Description]
END
GO
```

Comment: Consultation is still taking the same time
select all because the table has only one column.

Comment: It still a good practice to use a column name.  And there were other changes to the query.  Try an index on P.[Description] or better yet the PK on that table if Description is unique.

Comment: Down vote care to comment?  Come on what is the problem?

Comment: I did not vote in the negative , was another person. I am testing your solution, but still works the same way

Comment: If is still gives the same answer it did not deserve a down vote.  Start with an index on P.[Description] and if that does not fix it then materialize that select ... @FactId.  If you post a query plan on this I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

For your query you should be indexing the following:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_AdministrationPileDetail_LocalityId ON AdministrationPileDetail (LocalityID)
CREATE INDEX IX_AdministrationPileDetail_FactId ON AdministrationPileDetail (FactId)

CREATE INDEX IX_Locality_CountryId ON Locality(CountryId)
CREATE INDEX IX_Locality_ProvinceId ON Locality(ProvinceId)
CREATE INDEX IX_Locality_DepartmentId ON Locality(DepartmentId)
```

This is basic indexing in your FK, that is best practice to do.

Then if you still have problems you may consider to create an index in the column you are grouping by:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Province_Description ON Province(Description)
```

You may want to move the function outside and create a temporal table for it, instead of having it called on the WHERE.

```
SELECT 
   * 
INTO
   #Items
FROM  
   [gisoo].[ItemListToTable](@FactId)

CREATE IX_Items_FactId ON #Items(FactId)

SELECT  
    (apd.USS) as USS, (apd.Area) as Area, P.[Description] 
FROM
    [gisoo].AdministrationPileDetail apd
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Locality L on L.LocalityId = apd.LocalityId
INNER JOIN 
    [gisoo].Province P on P.CountryId = L.CountryId AND P.Provinceid = L.ProvinceId
INNER JOIN
    #Items i ON apd.FactId = i.FactId
WHERE 
    apd.FactId IN (SELECT * FROM  [gisoo].[ItemListToTable](@FactId))
    AND L.ProvinceId IS NOT NULL
    AND L.DepartmentId IS NOT NULL
```